# Is it possible to sync the Windows 8 Start Screen between machines?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Windows 8 PC Settings offers a way to sync desktop personalization themes, taskbar, wallpaper, etc. but it does not appear to offer a seamless way to sync tiles/shortcuts/apps between machines.

This is a real drag considering I use multiple machines and I'd like to have a consistent start screen on all machines.

I suppose I could use some run-of-the-mill cloud-based file system sync app to sync the specific folders that contain the start screen data, but that may contain unintended consequences with app shortcuts for apps that aren't install on all systems.

Anyhow, I'm open to any ideas, solutions or killer apps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually copy the file `appsFolder.itemdata-ms` from 1 PC to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 does sync some of the tiles on the start page, but it seems to be a little fragile. On my home laptop the Event Viewer > Applications and Services > Microsoft > Windows > SettingSync > Operational log is full of errors such as:

> (WLRoaming) Cloud sync engine failed to sync collection windows-contenttiles from cloud storage to the local cache (Result: 0x80041007)

I went to Settings > PC Settings > Users > Switch To Local Account and followed the instructions, then went back to the same and switched back to using my Microsoft account. This sent a code to my mobile phone which I had to enter on the laptop to have my Microsoft account trust the PC.

The event log (as above) now contains:

> (WLRoaming) Payload1 collections successfully downloaded

and my pinned tiles (a handful of IE web page links) from my other Windows machines have shown up on the start page.